# How to change firefox config with addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I want to change the user's firefox config settings with my addon. How do I do it and the config I want to change of my user's is related to opening link in same tab which would be switching browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction to 0.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an Addon-SDK extension use something like this:

```
var name = "browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction";
require("sdk/preferences/service").set(name, 0);
```

If it's a restartless or classic (overlay) extension you can use `nsIPrefService` and `nsIPrefBranch` (via `Services.jsm`)

```
var {classes:Cc, interfaces:Ci, utils:Cu, results:Cr, Constructor:CC} = Components;
const {Services} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm", {});
var branch = Services.prefs.getBranch("browser.link.open_newwindow.");
branch.setIntPref('restriction', 0);
```